# How to fix Akonadi unable to find mysql-global.conf Kubuntu 20.04?

Tags: kubuntu, mysql, kde, akonadi

I've had a database server reinstall. I had MariaDB installed and although it was functioning fine, some aspects specifically to MySQL workbench were finding it hard to be compatible with MariaDB. Eventually I replaced it with standard MySQL 8.0 installation. Till now the the whole system is working fine but it looks like the Akonadi service is not starting up properly.

I use KOrganizer to save all my events and since it depends on Akonadi, it is unable to launch. This is the status I get:

```
$ akonadictl start

Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Did not find MySQL server default configuration (mysql-global.conf)
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Failed to remove runtime connection config file
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...
```

Contrary to the third line, MySQL config files are present on this location:

```
$ /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

There's no way to do a reset for the service. Also I cannot reinstall it. Any suggestions?

**Edit**
After reinstallation of modules, I get this log when starting up Akonadi:

```
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/shivendra/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/shivendra/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket", "--pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid")
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stdout: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: exit code: 1
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: process error: "Unknown error"
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket' exists!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Failed to remove runtime connection config file
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Job error:  "" for collection: QVector() 

QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
org.kde.pim.akonadi_search_xapian: Xapian Database does not exist at  "/home/shivendra/.local/share/akonadi/search_db/calendars/"
org.kde.pim.akonadi_search_xapian: Xapian Database does not exist at  "/home/shivendra/.local/share/akonadi/search_db/contacts/"
org.kde.pim.akonadi_search_xapian: Xapian Database does not exist at  "/home/shivendra/.local/share/akonadi/search_db/email/"
org.kde.pim.akonadi_search_xapian: Xapian Database does not exist at  "/home/shivendra/.local/share/akonadi/search_db/notes/"
org.kde.pim.akonadiconsole: DatabaseOpeningError "DatabaseOpeningError: Couldn't detect type of database"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to reinstall the [package which provides *mysql-global.conf* file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=mysql-global.conf) by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall akonadi-backend-mysql
```

Comment: Now I'm getting new errors. Can you check and update?

Comment: Really I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: That's fine. Is there a way to set Akonadi to use SQLite instead of MySQL?

Comment: I do not know because I do not use it. I tried to answer the question on package-file level :)

Comment: No problem. KDE forums might have a solution.